# Turán's theorem proof

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I have a trouble with the following part of Turán's theorem. Some versions of the theorem are proved by exploiting lemma:

Turán graph $T_{k,n}$ is obtained by taking a set of $n$ vertices, dividing the vertices into $k$ classes in such a way that any two classes differ in size by at most one, and joining two vertices by an edge if and only if they are in different classes.

> The number of edges in $T_{k,n}$ is larger than the number of edges $T_{k-1,n}$.

Why does this hold?

Comment: @bof I have added the definition of Turan Graph, but Turans theorem is not needed here, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e(G)$ denote the number of edges in a graph $G.$

Recall that $K_{n_1,\dots,n_k}$ is the complete $k$-partite graph with vertex set $V=V_1\cup\cdots\cup V_k$ where the partite sets $V_i$ are pairwise disjoint, and two vertices are joined by an edge just in case they are in different partite sets.

$K_{n_1,\dots,n_k}$ is the Turán graph $T_{k,n}$ when $|n_i-n_j|\le1$ for all $i,j.$

**Lemma.** Let $n,k\in\mathbb N,\ k\le n.$ Among all graphs $K_{n_1,\dots,n_k}$ with $n_1+\cdots+n_k=n,$ the number of edges $e(K_{n_1,\dots,n_k})$ is maximized when $K_{n_1,\dots,n_k}$ is the Turán graph $T_{k,n}$.

**Proof.** Let $G=K_{n_1,\dots,n_k}$ be the graph with the maximum number of edges, and assume for a contradiction that $G$ is not the Turán graph. Then we have $|n_i-n_j|\gt1$ for some $i,j;$ without loss of generality, we may assume that $n_1-n_2\gt1.$ Then, since $(n_1-1)(n_2+1)\gt n_1n_2,$ we have $e(K_{n_1-1,n_2+1,n_3,\dots,n_k})\gt e(G),$ contradicting the masimality of $G.$

**Theorem.** If $2\le k\le n,$ then $e(T_{k-1,n})\lt e(T_{k,n}).$

**Proof.** Let $T_{k-1,n}=K_{n_1,\dots,n_{k-1}}$ where $n_1\ge n_2\ge\cdots\ge n_{k-1}.$ Then
$$e(T_{k-1,n})=e(K_{n_1,n_2,\dots,n_{k-1}})\lt e(K_{1,n_1-1,n_2,\dots,n_{k-1}})\le e(T_{k,n}),$$
the last inequality from the Lemma.

For the penultimate inequality, observe that, if $G_1$ is a complete $(k-1)$-partite graph with partite sets $V_1,V_2,\dots,V_{k-1},$ and if we partition $V_1$ into two disjoint nonempty sets $V_1',V_1''$ and let $G_2$ be the complete $k$-partite graph with partite sets $V_1',V_1'',V_2,\dots,V_{k-1},$ then $e(G_1)\lt e(G_2),$ because $G_2$ has all the edges of $G_1$ plus additional edges between $V_1'$ and $V_1''.$

Comment: This looks almost finished. However, I miss an argument for the penultimate inequality.

Comment: I have added an argument for the penultimate inequality to my answer.

Comment: Great! Now I see.